# Spring Circular Reference injection issues

Tags: java, spring

I have a scheduled task in Spring which executes every 24 hours which I can also trigger as an asychronous task at any point. When it fires, I get the following exception.

```
org.exampletest.toa.data.error.DataAccessException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.interceptor': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.exampletest.toa.data.pool.implementations.UserService.getObjectFromOriginalDataSource(UserService.java:60) ~[helpsteps-core-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.exampletest.toa.data.pool.implementations.UserService.getObjectFromOriginalDataSource(UserService.java:28) ~[helpsteps-core-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.exampletest.toa.data.pool.ObjectPool.getObjectFromDataSource(ObjectPool.java:241) ~[helpsteps-core-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.exampletest.toa.data.pool.ObjectPool.getCopy(ObjectPool.java:133) ~[helpsteps-core-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.exampletest.toa.data.pool.implementations.UserService.getCopy(UserService.java:82) ~[helpsteps-core-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.exampletest.toa.messaging.dispatch.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:162) ~[helpsteps-core-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.exampletest.toa.messaging.dispatch.MessageDispatcher.dispatchNightly(MessageDispatcher.java:82) ~[helpsteps-core-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.interceptor': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:342) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(Cglib2AopProxy.java:654) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:605) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.exampletest.toa.access.PrivilegedMethodInterceptor$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6ed9064e.invoke(<generated>) ~[cglib-2.2.2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy190.getGroupSubscribers(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.exampletest.toa.data.implementations.mysql.MySQLUserDAO.fillInGroupDetails(MySQLUserDAO.java:8406) ~[helpsteps-core-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.exampletest.toa.data.implementations.mysql.MySQLUserDAO.setUserRelationships(MySQLUserDAO.java:2698) ~[helpsteps-core-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.exampletest.toa.data.implementations.mysql.MySQLUserDAO.getUser(MySQLUserDAO.java:5314) ~[helpsteps-core-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="messageDispatcher" class="org.exampletest.toa.messaging.dispatch.MessageDispatcher" scope="singleton">
    <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO_raw"/>
    <property name="userService" ref="userPool_raw"/>
</bean>

<bean id="groupDAO_raw" class="org.exampletest.toa.data.implementations.mysql.MySQLGroupDAO" scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSources" ref="dataSources"/>
    <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO_raw" />
    ...

<bean id="userDAO_raw" class="org.exampletest.toa.data.implementations.mysql.MySQLUserDAO" scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSources" ref="dataSources"/>
    <property name="groupDAO" ref="groupDAO_raw" />
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="userPool_raw" class="org.exampletest.toa.data.pool.implementations.UserService" scope="singleton">
    <property name="dao" ref="userDAO_raw" />
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="userDAO" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">

    <property name="target">
        <ref bean="userDAO_raw"/>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>interceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="groupDAO" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target">
        <ref bean="groupDAO_raw"/>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>interceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="userPool" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target">
        <ref bean="userPool_raw"/>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>interceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean> 

 <bean id="interceptor" class="org.exampletest.toa.access.PrivilegedMethodInterceptor" scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    <property name="environment" ref="environment" />
    <property name="session" ref="toasession" />
    <property name="methodContextManager" ref="methodContextManager" />
    <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO_raw" />
    ...
</bean>
```

I'm confused. I'm injecting the 'raw' userDAO and userPool into my tasks class (MessageDispatcher) and I'm injecting the 'raw' groupDAO into the userDAO and vice versa, but the exception seems to indicate that Spring is still creating a proxy object for the groupDAO. Is there a problem with the circular reference injection? (I thought Spring handled that automatically.) I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. We actually have a couple application contexts that get imported into the base applicationContext.xml, depending on our deployment. In one of these imported application contexts, I was overriding the default 'userDAO' bean and I failed to inject the 'groupDAO_raw' bean into that overriding 'userDAO' bean. So failing to do that must have injected the proxy reference in there instead, causing the problems. Once I injected the raw bean into the overriding userDAO bean, life got better.